# STL-pair-like triplet class - do I roll my own?

Tags: c++, std, stdtuple, triplet

I want to use a triplet class, as similar as possible to std::pair. STL doesn't seem to have one. I don't want to use something too heavy, like Boost. Is there some useful FOSS non-restrictive-license triplet class I could lift from somewhere? Should I roll my own? Should I do something else entirely?

**Edit:** About `std::tuple`...

Is there really no benefit to a triplet-specific class? I mean, with tuple, I can't do

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3> std::tuple<T1, T2, T3> triple;
```

now can I? Won't I have to typedef individual-type-combination triples?

Comment: I'd say `std::tuple`.

Comment: If for some reason you do not have access to `std::tuple` (non-C++11 compliant compiler, for instance), consider `std::pair<T, std::pair<U, V> >`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: That would make element references quite cumbersome and uninituitive.

Comment: But element references are already unintuitive with `std::pair`.  How often do you really want elements called `first` and `second` (rather than e.g. `key` and `value`, or `name` and `surname`).

Comment: @JamesKanze: `mytriple.second.second` is much more confusing than `mytriple.third`.

Comment: @einpoklum True.  But it's rare that either would be appropriate.  Perhaps in some numeric applications, but otherwise: it's better to signal semantic intent directly.

Comment: It is hilarious that, with all the talk (here and below) of convenience/inconvenience of accessing members of a std::tuple, nobody actually demonstrated the accessor syntax!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

No, don't roll your own. Instead, take a look at [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) - it's a generalization of `std::pair`. So here's a value-initialized triple of `int`s:

```
std::tuple<int, int, int> triple;
```

If you want, you can have a type alias for triples only:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
using triple = std::tuple<T1, T2, T3>;
```

Comment: Thanks. Used this. However, I feel like I have sinned. Wondering, if using a struct would have been cleaner.

Answer (score 7):

If you can use C++11, use std::tuple

If not, use boost::tuple

Answer (score 6):

If you're using C++11, you can use [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

If you're using C++03, then you'll either need to resort to rolling your own (which isn't too hard), or using `tuple` from Boost.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct triplet
{
    T first, middle, last;
};

template<typename T>
triplet<T> make_triplet(const T &m1, const T &m2, const T &m3) 
{
    triplet<T> ans;
    ans.first = m1;
    ans.middle = m2;
    ans.last = m3;
    return ans;
}
```

Examples of usage:

```
triplet<double> aaa;
aaa = make_triplet<double>(1.,2.,3.);
cout << aaa.first << " " << aaa.middle << " "  << aaa.last << endl;

triplet<bool> bbb = make_triplet<bool>(false,true,false);
cout << bbb.first << " " << bbb.middle << " "  << bbb.last << endl;
```

I'm using this and it is enough for my purposes... If you want different types, though, just do some modifications:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct triplet
{
    T1 first; 
    T2 middle;
    T3 last;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
triplet<T1,T2,T3> make_triplet(const T1 &m1, const T2 &m2, const T3 &m3) 
{
    triplet<T1,T2,T3> ans;
    ans.first = m1;
    ans.middle = m2;
    ans.last = m3;
    return ans;
}
```

And the usage will be very similar:

```
triplet<bool,string,myDouble> ccc;
ccc = make_triplet<bool,string,double>(false,"AB",3.1415);
ccc.middle = "PI";
cout << ccc.first << " " << ccc.middle << " "  << ccc.last << endl;
```

Comment: There is a small mistake in your code. The definition of `make_triplet` should be `triplet<T1,T2,T3> make_triplet(const T1 &m1, const T2 &m2, const T3 &m3)`

Comment: Get error message when I use: `vector< triplet<double, double, double> > v;
  v.emplace_back(1,2,3);`

Answer (score -1):

To add the aspect of similarity to std::pair, you could define a class that has first, second and third. My guess is that in In that case you cannot avoid making a subclass of std::pair and add a 'third' member. It's a few lines of code.

Furthermore, if you often use these things with the same type, you could make twins and triplet classes as well. Easily made with C++-11's 'using', like:

```
template <typename T> using twins = std::pair<T,T>;
```

Comment: Oh no, a triplet class should definitely not be a subclass of `std::pair`. A triplet is not a kind-of-a-pair, like a `std::pair<T,U>` is not a subclass of `T` nor of `U`.

Comment: I don't see your point. A twin is a pair where Tand U are the same class, triplet has 3 of the same type. Any triplet can be usef where any twin can be usef.

Comment: That is absolutely not true. With a pair, you rely on there being exactly two pieces of data; with a triplet, you make a contradictory assumption. Not only can they not be subclasses, but they cannot be used interchangeably.

Comment: Sorry I disagree. Anywhere you need a twin you can use a triplet, but not the other way around. That's exactly the idea of inheritance, the LSK applies perfectly. Moreover, because the members are called 'first' and 'second' parameterized functions and classes get exactly what they need from a pair even when in fact they operate on a triplet. Very standard and very OK.